# Azure "MySQL server has gone away" for one minute only

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm using Azure App Services to run about 15 PHP web apps. Most of these apps connect to my 'Azure Database for MySQL server' instance. This is a Basic-tier instance (1 vCore & 2GB memory).

The MySQL instance hosts about 30 small databases (ranging between 1 to 100MB in size).

The load on the MySQL instance is stable and low. CPU is constantly under 20%, memory is constantly under 50% and IO does not even show up in the metrics in the Azure Portal.

My problem is this:

Every once in a while the server goes offline for about 1 or 2 minutes (max 5 min). I see that client applications try to connect, they hang for a while to finally get the error:

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away`

It seems to happen randomly. Sometimes a few times a week or even a day. But sometimes it doesn't happen for weeks.

What's noticeable though, when it happens I see a downward spike in memory and an upward spike in CPU in the metrics graph on the portal like this:

[image: Azure MySQL server has gone away]

Does anyone experience the same issue on Azure Database for MySQL? And did anyone find a solution?

I'm starting to think that it's caused by a resources movement on the Azure side but I don't have any evidence to back that up. If so, shouldn't that happen without any downtime?

Comment: Can you please send me the name of your server and the Azure region it is located in? andrea.lam@microsoft.com

Comment: I've send you the name and region per email. Thank you.

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size, # cores of your MySQL Host server 
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scaling up from the Basic 1 core tier with Compute Gen 4 to Basic 2 core tier with Compute Gen 5 seemed to resolve the problem.

Not sure though what was causing the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

I started experiencing this error in May 2019.

If I happen to be connected on the mariadb server with ssh at the time it occurs and `htop` is running, I can see `rsyslog` suddenly going crazy. It bogs down the CPU and the network connection becomes unresponsive. The CPU and network activity doesn't show up in Azure but running `w` in the ssh session after the network recovers shows the CPU load was definitely very high during the last 15 minutes.

I traced it back to OMS agent. When that service is killed on the mariadb server, the server runs without any problem. As soon as OMS agent is started, "Mysql has gone away" pops up on the clients within 24 hours due to unresponsive network connection with the server machine.

It is possible to uninstall OMS agent from the Azure portal but it comes back within 48H.

The only way I found of getting rid of OMS agent is to stop `walinuxagent` too on the linux server.

Scaling the server up may solve the problem as you have more CPU power to process the extra CPU load induced by OMS agent. I prefer to kill OMS agent and `walinuxagent` instead of spending more money on an expansive server.

**Edit:**

It turns out OMS is installed because the VM is part of a Log Analytics workspace (search for Log Analytics workspaces in the search bar). Removing the VM from the workspace immediately uninstall OMS. There is no need to stop `walinuxagent`.